# HSQLDB updateRow() does not update

Tags: java, hsqldb

HSQLDB 2.4.0, JAVA 8u151: A very simple example to show the updateXX() and updateRow() methods on an updateable RecordSet do not update anything!? Instead the unchanged row is reported again.

In this example I could certainly use a SQL UPDATE statement, but in my real application I definitely want to rely on mechanism of an updateable RecordSet. How to do it?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String path = "c:/UpdateTest";
        String connectionString = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:" + path;
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            stmt.executeUpdate("create cached table data (id int, name varchar(30));");
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into data (id,name ) values (1, 'Jack')");
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into data (id,name ) values (2, null)");
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into data (id,name ) values (3, 'Jim')");

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from data");
            while (rs.next()) {
                outputRow(rs);
            }
            System.out.println();

            rs.absolute(2);
            rs.updateInt("id", 5);
            rs.updateRow();
            rs.refreshRow();
            outputRow(rs); //what about the update??

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void outputRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            System.out.print(rs.getObject(i) + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the rs.updateRow() is successful, the row is update in the database.

HSQLDB ResultSet objects do not show the changed row, even after calling refreshRow().